# What is the difference between these mixing-angle equations?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

In the following [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9303287) the mixing angle of the neutrinos is given by:

$$\sin^2 2\theta = \frac{\mu^2}{\mu^2 +[c\Gamma_\alpha E /M +M/2]^2} \tag{1}$$

where $\mu$ represents the Dirac mass , M represents the Majorana mass for the right-handed components and $\Gamma$ represents the collision rate .

But I was told that for neutrinos, based on a see-saw type I mechanism, and on the mass matrix the following is true :

$$\mu^2 = \sin^2 (\theta) m^2_s \tag{2}$$

What is the difference between these two? Is one of them in the vacuum and the other one not?

Comment: I think I found an answer to this problem:

The first equation represents the interaction with background, whilst the second represents it in the vacuum.
In the vacuum the interaction term $\Gamma$ can be considered to be 0 and because in the article above mentioned, $M \gg \mu$ the \mu^2 in the denominator can be ignored ($\mu^2 + M \approx M$) .

Because the angle is so small $\sin^2 2\theta \approx sin^2 \theta$